# Getting the Current Theme in Yii

Tags: php, yii, themes

I want to get the name of the current theme that is used by my Yii Framework Project.

I had tried the following codes, and got no success

```
Yii::app()->getTheme();

Yii::app()->theme;
```

what is the code that will return the current theme name that my Yii project is currently using?

thanks

Comment: Maybe because you didn't open up the Yii API. If you did, you would have solved it. Although I did not downvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Yii::app()->theme` returns instance of [CTheme](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTheme). You can use the `name` property:

```
Yii::app()->theme->name
```

Comment: i am newbie in yii. i got "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" when i echo Yii::app()->theme->name.

Comment: @Maulikpatel You probably didn't set theme in config. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#theme-detail

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Yii::app()->theme->getName()` also

Comment: Yup it's the same thing. Most of Yii's classes have those magic methods defined.